# I created two constructors but can only create an instance using one of them

Tags: c#, oop, constructor

EDIT:
I am working with company property here and the concept is something that should make sense to the people reading this post:
I have 2 constructors for EFImport, one has 2 arguments the other has 3 arguments. What I am suggesting is that my constructor with 2 arguments is not being recognized. I am using the new keyword, and am initializing the object in the exact same manner with the constructor that has 3 arguments and it works perfectly. BUT the constructor with 2 arguments is not being identified. Again, I cannot specifically put up the code here but the concept is what I am asking about.

I have a need to use two different constructors, one that takes an extra argument, and one that does not need that argument. I am not sure exactly why I am not able to actually reach the constructor that has only two arguments.

I have the following constructors:

```
public EFImport(string empId, Class A instanceA, IEnumerable<ClassB> instanceB)
{
     //do stuff here
}

public EFImport(string empId, Class A instanceA)
{
     //do other different stuff here
}
```

I am trying to call the constructors like this:

```
Public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string fEmp)
{
     //do stuff here
     //call constructor here:
     //NEW keyword is used here
     var fileImp = new EFImport(empId, instanceA, instanceB);
     //this works just fine
}

Public HttpResponseMessage Put([FromBody]string empImportId)
{
     //do stuff here
     //call constructor here:
     //NEW keyword used here
     var fileImp = new EFImport(empId, instanceA);
     //Here it gives me the error stated below
}
```

Error 509   '`EFImport`' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments

What exactly am I doing wrong? Both constructors are public and the constructor with 3 arguments works perfectly fine, but the compiler does not see the constructor taking 2 arguments. Am I overlooking something really simple?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ClassA` instead of `Class A`?  Neatness counts.

Comment: Are you sure you posted code that can compile?

Comment: @AlexM. of course not `var EFImport(empId, instanceA, instanceB)` :)

Comment: Please post your actual code if you want assistance with it.  In the abstract sense, you certainly can have constructors with differing numbers of arguments.

Comment: @stephen.vakil technically the code is company property so I cannot actually use the original code. Let me see if I can elaborate on the code

Comment: Obviously `var EFImport(empId, instanceA)` doesn't make any sense.  Does the *real code* read something like `var whatever = new EFImport(empId, instanceA);`?

Comment: Are you sure `empId` is a string and that `instanceA` is an instance of `ClassA`? I'm guessing you may not have noticed that the error usually has a complimenting one, like "Could not implicitly convert argument N from X to Y" or something like that...

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = new EFImport(empId, instanceA);
```

and

```
var obj = new EFImport(empId, instanceA, instanceB);
```

should work.

Comment: `should work.` Why? how about explaining what is the problem in OP's code, how he can fix it and why it should work.

Comment: I don't think the op will read it Just like the results for `c# constructor` on Google. I can tell him that he have to instantiate objects with the `new` keyword and that he has to assign it to a variable to use it further on but TL;DR.

Comment: `I don't think the op will read`, So what is the purpuse of your post. To explain it  to us?  We already can solve problems ourselves.

Comment: @Tarabass firstly I did read this, and secondly I am using the new keyword. The bottom line is that I have 2 constructors, one that takes 3 arguments and another that takes 2. I have an error that says that I do not have a constructor associated with that object that takes only 2 arguments. I am using the new keyword, and your condescending tone is very unappreciated, and seems to be against the concept of this website.

Answer (score 0):

I don't seem to know what you are doing with:

`var EFImport(empId, instanceA)`

You have a few issues with this code:

- You are instantiating the object incorrectly. In C# if you want to create a new object you would use:

  ```
  TypeOfVar nameOfVar = new TypeOfVar();
  ```

  or

  ```
  var nameOfVar = new TypeOfVar();
  ```

  More information on how to use constructors in C# can be found at:    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx
- You also seem to be missing your semicolons ;)

Comment: I edited the code to show that I am in fact instantiating the objects correctly. I am asking a specific question related to the error - why is the constructor with 2 arguments not being recognized. That's all I am asking.